# Creating a Singleton EventEmittor in Nodejs & Express Project

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, eventemitter

I'm trying to create a Publisher-Subscriber pattern with Nodejs eventEmitters for my nodejs/express API project. My use-case is fairly simple:

1. I want to emit events from various places in my project. For example, emit an event when a new user is created.
2. Then I want a single place, where I listen to all the events and decide what actions to take.

This will require a singleton instance of eventEmitter because 'emit' and 'on' calls should happen on the same instance of 'event' object.

To achieve it, this is how my ***index.js*** looks:

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()

const bodyParser = require('body-parser')
const routes = require('./api/routes')
const EventEmitter = require("events");
const eventEmitter = new EventEmitter();

const eventListeners = require('../src/subscribers/events');
//const eventSubs = new eventListeners();

app.use(eventListeners.eventSubscribers());

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

app.set('eventEmitter', eventEmitter);

app.get('/', (req, res) => res.send('App is working'))

app.use('/api', routes)

app.listen(3000, () => console.log('Example app listening on port 3000!'))

module.exports = {
  app
}
```

This is how my ***middleware/controller*** function looks(where I'm emitting event):

```
const createUser = async (req, res, next) => {
  var user = req.body
  try {
    console.log('in controller');

    await newUser(user)

    console.log(req.app.get('eventEmitter'));

    req.app.get('eventEmitter').emit('USER_CREATED', {email: user.email, name: user.name})

    res.status(200).send({success: true});
    next()

  } catch(e) {
    console.log(e.message)
    res.sendStatus(500) && next(e)
  }
}
```

And, this is how my ***event subscriber*** file looks:

```
const eventSubscribers = (req) => {
    const eventEmitter = req.app.get('eventEmitter');

    eventEmitter.on('USER_CREATED', ({ email, name }) => {
        console.log('event fired and captured')
    })
}
```

Using this, the event is getting emitted, but the event subscriber is not getting trigerred. I think there is something wrong with the way I'm accessing req/app objects in my subscriber. Also, I'm getting

```
TypeError: eventListeners.eventSubscribers is not a function
```

error in my index.js file. Questions I have:

1. Is this the right way to create a publisher/subscriber pattern?
2. How do I access req/app object instances in my event subscriber?
3. What's the best way to make sure event subscriber file is loaded when the app loads?

Comment: EventEmitter should be imported as follows: `const { EventEmitter } = require ('events');`. Events module has other classes and properties and right now you are not importing it as expected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming everything else is correctly setup by you,
I think the cause of the error that you mentioned

```
TypeError: eventListeners.eventSubscribers is not a function
```

is that no function is passed to the middleware i.e as a middleware, shouldn't you just pass the eventListeners.eventSubscribers like this

```
app.use(eventListeners.eventSubscribers);
```

instead of like this

```
app.use(eventListeners.eventSubscribers());
```

If we compare both expressions above, express is not able to pass the request object in the second case as you are calling it but this function call is returning nothing to the express i.e kind of void, but in first case since you passed the function object reference to express, it then calls it as middleware(as a callback later and passes the request object in it while calling it).

Alternatively I think you don't need to use middleware for using the EventEmitter, you can just keep a single global custom instance consisting of EventEmitter as it's property and all the different event you want to listen, and then just use them wherever you require them.You can use the EventEmitter as a property of this custom to emit event in whatever module you want to by importing this custom module there.

This is the working example below

index.js file/entry file

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')
const routes = require("./userRoute");
//const eventSubs = new eventListeners();
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

app.get('/', (req, res) => res.send('App is working'))

app.use('/api', routes);

app.listen(3000, () => console.log('Example app listening on port 3000!'))
```

This is our global singleton custom instance using EventEmitter as a property.

```
const { EventEmitter } = require("events");

class CustomEventEmitter {

    eventEmitter;

    constructor() {
        this.eventEmitter = new EventEmitter();
        this.initialize();
    }

    getEventEmitter() {
        return this.eventEmitter;
    }

    initialize() {
        this.eventEmitter.on('USER_CREATED', ({ email, name }) => {
            console.log('event fired and captured with data', email, name);
        });
    }
}

module.exports = new CustomEventEmitter();
```

and here we use our global CustomEventEmitter module in our request routes
i.e userRoute.js

```
const router = require("express").Router();
const customEventEmitter = require("./CustomEventEmitter");

const createUser = async (req, res, next) => {
    var user = req.body
    try {
        console.log('in controller');

        // await newUser(user)

        customEventEmitter.getEventEmitter().emit('USER_CREATED', { email: user.email, name: user.name })

        res.status(200).send({ success: true });
        next()

    } catch (e) {
        console.log(e.message)
        res.sendStatus(500) && next(e)
    }
}

router.post("/createUser", createUser)

module.exports = router;
```

Comment: When I make this change, my TypeError goes away but, when I call CreateUser API from postman, application hangs. It goes inside my eventSubscriber, but does not come out of it.

Comment: @VikalpJain are you sure, you are using EventEmitter in correct way, the comment has a mention of another way of importing EventEmitter. alternatively I think you don't need to use middleware for using the EventEmitter, you can just keep a single global custom instance consisting of EventEmitter as a property of it and all the different event you want to listen, and then just use them in main entry file.You can use the EventEmitter as a property of this custom to emit event in whatever module you want to by importing this custom module there.

Comment: No, I'm not sure. In-fact I'm trying to achieve what you described in your comment, but unable to structure it. Would you be able to explain it with some code? Thanks.

Comment: @VikalpJain updated the answer with working alternative example

Comment: thanks a lot! This clears things up a.lot. I'm gonna try this out in the morning and get back!